# Как в гугл таблицах определить, что ячейка содержит цену в долларах, а не рублях?

Tags: google-spreadsheet

Собственно, сам вопрос в заголовке.
Есть такой столбец и нужно в формуле определять,   относится ли она к доллару (и, соответственно, переводим цену в рубли) или к рублям - и тогда не переводим.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не скажу за *Google*-таблицы, а в *Excel* таких встроенных функций нет. Или применение макрофункций, или UDF писать (и то, и другое требует разрешения на использование макросов).

Comment: Ну с макросами-то можно этого добиться, думаю

Comment: А в экселе можно узнать как раз, по формату в ячейке

Comment: Но в гугле там оно не работает ):

Comment: В *Exсel* - `ЯЧЕЙКА("формат")` может некорректно определить валюту. Или что-то появилось в новых версиях? И если Вам неинтересен `Excel`, зачем указали метку?

Comment: Указал, потому что я далеко не всё про эксель знаю и может там есть аналоги. Схожесть гугл таблиц и эксель очевидна вроде.